# tensorflow RuntimeError: Coordinator stopped with threads still running: Thread-#

Tags: tensorflow

When doing validation I am always running into "RuntimeError: Coordinator stopped with threads still running"
Like some error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "cli.py", line 67, in main
    run.train(config, val_config=val_config)
  File "F:\NLP-cse517_2017_UW\hw5\run.py", line 206, in train
    train_run.join_queue(coord)
  File "F:\NLP-cse517_2017_UW\hw5\run.py", line 114, in join_queue
    iq.join(coord)
  File "F:\NLP-cse517_2017_UW\hw5\input_queue.py", line 60, in join
    coord.join(self.threads)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\coordinator.py", line 397, in join
    " ".join(stragglers))
RuntimeError: Coordinator stopped with threads still running: Thread-4
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1136, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1118, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: Enqueue operation was cancelled
         [[Node: random_shuffle_queue_enqueue = QueueEnqueueV2[Tcomponents=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT64], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](random_shuffle_queue, _arg_x_0_3, _arg_q_0_1, _arg_y1_0_5, _arg_y2_0_6, _arg_x_len_0_4, _arg_q_len_0_2, _arg_idxs_0_0)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "F:\NLP-cse517_2017_UW\hw5\input_queue.py", line 49, in _thread_main
    sess.run(self._enqueue_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 786, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 994, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1129, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1149, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: Enqueue operation was cancelled
         [[Node: random_shuffle_queue_enqueue = QueueEnqueueV2[Tcomponents=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT64], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](random_shuffle_queue, _arg_x_0_3, _arg_q_0_1, _arg_y1_0_5, _arg_y2_0_6, _arg_x_len_0_4, _arg_q_len_0_2, _arg_idxs_0_0)]]

Caused by op 'random_shuffle_queue_enqueue', defined at:
  File "cli.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "cli.py", line 67, in main
    run.train(config, val_config=val_config)
  File "F:\NLP-cse517_2017_UW\hw5\run.py", line 183, in train
    train_run = Run(config, val_config=val_config)
  File "F:\NLP-cse517_2017_UW\hw5\run.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.iq = InputQueue(config, self.data)
  File "F:\NLP-cse517_2017_UW\hw5\input_queue.py", line 32, in __init__
    for placeholders in self._placeholders_list
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py", line 322, in enqueue
    self._queue_ref, vals, name=scope)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1589, in _queue_enqueue_v2
    name=name)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

CancelledError (see above for traceback): Enqueue operation was cancelled
         [[Node: random_shuffle_queue_enqueue = QueueEnqueueV2[Tcomponents=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT64], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](random_shuffle_queue, _arg_x_0_3, _arg_q_0_1, _arg_y1_0_5, _arg_y2_0_6, _arg_x_len_0_4, _arg_q_len_0_2, _arg_idxs_0_0)]]
```

Sometimes this can be fixed with specifying 'TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL', so there are no warnings ahead.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Did you use monitored session?

Comment: No, I didn't. I think I just used tf.Session

Comment: Could you please try MonitoredSession and see whether this is happening or not?